# Write True/False into a new column based on inbuilt condition (global_land_mask)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file containing a set of locations (lats & lons) among other variables, and I wanted to identify which of these locations are on land using the *global_land_mask* library. I wanted to write the result (True/False) in a new column (*'Land_Sea'*).

|  | State | ID | Station_Name | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013 | TX | ABI | Abilene | 32.4106 | -99.6821 |
| 2014 | TX | GYF | Alaminos Canyon Block 857 | 26.129 | -94.898 |
| 2015 | TX | ALI | ALICE INTL AIRPORT | 27.7409 | -98.0269 |
| 2016 | TX | E38 | ALPINE | 30.384 | -103.684 |
| 2017 | TX | AMA | AMARILLO ARPT (AWOS) | 35.2194 | -101.706 |

Here is the code I tried using. It ran but gave no output. I have tried using different methods I found online to no avail. What could I be doing wrong, please?

```
import pandas as pd
from global_land_mask import globe

texas = pd.read_csv('tx.csv')
# Create a column, title it, and put in the data. Syntax: df.insert(col index, 'col name', 'data')
tx_land_sea = texas.insert(5, 'Land_Sea', globe.is_land(texas['Latitude'], texas['Longitude']))
tx_land_sea
```

Comment: Use `texas.apply()`.

Comment: Please confirm that you are implying that I should replace *texas.insert()* with texas.apply(). Please, clarify

Comment: Well, there's more to it, it's not just a drop-in replacement. Read the documentation of apply to see how to use it.

Comment: `insert` operation does not return anything. If you print the dataframe `texas` the changes should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
# is the lat/lon on land ?
on_land = [
    globe.is_land(lat, lon) for lat,lon in zip(
        texas['Latitude'], texas['Longitude'])
]

#another variant with `.apply`
# on_land = texas.apply(lambda x: globe.is_land(x['Latitude'], x['Longitude']), axis=1)

tx_land_sea = texas.assign(Land_Sea=on_land) #the new col is inserted at the end
```

Output :

```
print(tx_land_sea)

     State   ID               Station_Name  Latitude  Longitude  Land_Sea
2013    TX  ABI                    Abilene  32.41063  -99.68209      True
2014    TX  GYF  Alaminos Canyon Block 857  26.12900  -94.89800     False
2015    TX  ALI         ALICE INTL AIRPORT  27.74089  -98.02694      True
2016    TX  E38                     ALPINE  30.38400 -103.68400      True
2017    TX  AMA       AMARILLO ARPT (AWOS)  35.21936 -101.70592      True
```